# Delaying animations and showing only on scroll

Tags: jquery, css

Actually this site has what I want: http://www.3magine.com/our-work/

I can see that all of the animations are done with css3, but how do they delay the animations and show the content only on scroll?

without javascript it is not impossible as I understand?

Comment: Is there a valid SO question in here?

Comment: This websites commonly referred to acronym is SO (Stack Overflow)

Comment: I think it is a valid question. I am bulding this animation with css3 and I would like to make the same on scroll > show animations effect, so maybe anybody would be able to give some tips on how to achieve this.

Comment: Your last comment gave some more detail. Edit your post and add that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your last question, no, this cannot be accomplished with strictly CSS (and why would you want too, JS is awesome).

This site uses some JS combined with CSS3 to accomplish these things.

Take a look at the linked JS file. They use this on the website you mentioned

http://www.3magine.com/wp-content/themes/3magine/js/jquery.appear-1.1.1.modified.js (The jQuery appear plugin which is also on Google Code)

combined with this css file

http://www.3magine.com/wp-content/themes/3magine/css/animations.css

to accomplish all this fanciness. After all those have been linked they use the following code to implement it all on the page

```
if(Modernizr.csstransitions){               
                var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
                script.type = 'text/javascript';
                script.src = "http://www.3magine.com/wp-content/themes/3magine/js/jquery.appear-1.1.1.modified.js";
                $('head').append( script );
                                document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.3magine.com/wp-content/themes/3magine/css/animations.css" />');
                $(function(){

                    //rewind all animations and remove classes when they appear
                    $('.sequential').appear({
                        once:true,
                        forEachVisible:function(i,e){   if(i==0)return; $(e).addClass('delay'+i); },
                        appear:function(){      $(this).removeClass('init').removeClass('disappear');   },
                        disappear:function(){   $(this).addClass('disappear');  }
                    });
                    $('.sequentialChildren > *').each(function(ic,e){
                        //if(i==0) return;  $(e).addClass('delay'+i);
                        $(e).appear({
                            once:true,
                            forEachVisible:function(i,e){   if(ic==0)   return; $(e).addClass('delay'+ic); },
                            appear:function(){      $(this).removeClass('init').removeClass('disappear');   },
                            disappear:function(){   $(this).addClass('disappear');  }
                        });
                    });
                });
            }
```

It's a lot of code to wade through, but it shouldn't be too hard to understand. Also you'll notice at the top of the code block I posted, it starts with

```
if(!Modernizr.csstransitions)
```

Modernizr (http://modernizr.com/) is a HTML5/CSS3 feature browser detection JS library. This site uses that library to ensure the user's browser is feature compliant with the code being written.

Another popular CSS animations library is Animate.css
http://daneden.me/animate/

Check out all of these things and you should be off to a good start

Answer (score 2):

You'll find a full tutorial on how we built the homepage animations at http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/getting-animations-trigger-right-time

Hope this helps.